# python/django - View in Footer ( view in all urlpatterns )

Tags: django, view, django-queryset

Finally it's easy for me to get some query set in a view and print in template.

But, now I have huge problem... I normal case as You know are two steps, adding view in views.py , in this view setting up what gueryset I want to use in one off the templates. Then I setting up the url for that view, for exmaple. exmaple.com/projects/ and it is showing last projects in this particular page. 
But I want to show the last projects on footer which one is allways visible on any urls... I cannot sort this out...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: It is too broad to explain here but you should read about [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)